# How does the Django-REST-Framework store the user's authentication token?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Reading the Django REST framework documentation, I understand that token authentication can be created and for a user:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

token = Token.objects.create(user=...)
print(token.key)
```

And then checked on a view-by-view basis.

When accessing the API from the command line, the documentation shows that the Token is supplied in the header like so:

`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'`

My question is, when going through the browsable API, how does Django already know my user token without having to supply it like in the curl command?

Comment: You probably also have SessionAuthentication enabled.

Comment: But how is the `request.auth` variable updated?

Comment: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L133

Comment: I understand that, but when you log in, through the admin page for example, how does Django persistently remember who I am when I go to another page?

Comment: Django's session framework sets a cookie in your browser that correlates with a session identifier, which contains, among other things, your logged-in user ID: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Thank you! So if you were to only interact with your API through a front end (like react) and you were using TokenAuthentication, you would need to manually store the token and use it every time you make a request to the API?

Comment: Yes, that's how it'd go.